# WP_QUERY with both author and post_type set (makes me crazy)

Tags: wp-query, author, post-type

If I do this

```
    $args2 = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
         );
      $query2 = new WP_Query($args2);
    error_log($query2->request);
```

Then I see this result

```
     SELECT   hAvlYjZV_posts.*
                        FROM hAvlYjZV_posts  LEFT JOIN hAvlYjZV_term_relationships ON (hAvlYjZV_posts.ID = hAvlYjZV_term_relationships.object_id)
                        WHERE 1=1  AND (
  hAvlYjZV_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (5841)
) AND hAvlYjZV_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status <> 'trash' AND hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft'))
                        GROUP BY hAvlYjZV_posts.ID
                        ORDER BY hAvlYjZV_posts.post_date DESC
```

Means I no filter by author in $args2, post_type = 'post'.

If I do instead this

```
    $args2 = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'author' => $user_id,
    );
    $query2 = new WP_Query($args2);
    error_log($query2->request);
```

Then I receive this query in request

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  hAvlYjZV_posts.ID
                                        FROM hAvlYjZV_posts
                                        WHERE 1=1  AND hAvlYjZV_posts.post_author IN (17)  AND ((hAvlYjZV_posts.post_type = 'libri' AND (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_author = 17 AND hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'private'))) OR (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_type = 'ricette' AND (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_author = 17 AND hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'private'))) OR (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_type = 'cpt_interviste' AND (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_author = 17 AND hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'private'))) OR (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_type = 'rubriche_originali' AND (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR (hAvlYjZV_posts.post_author = 17 AND hAvlYjZV_posts.post_status = 'private'))))

                                        ORDER BY hAvlYjZV_posts.post_date DESC
                                        LIMIT 0, 15
```

Means I filter by author the WP_Query and it search me all custom post_type ('libri', 'ricette", ...) even if I asked for post_type=post.

This is crazy to me... why like that???

Thanks.
Ioria